# Why is my outline hidden when I hold the mouse down on my element?

Tags: html, css

When I focus this control it gets an outline, as desired, but when I click with the primary mouse button and hold then the outline disappears whilst I hold it.  How can I fix it?

```css
:root {
  --color-mint: #02b689;
  --color-white: #ffffff;
  --color-silver: #c2c2c2;
  --focus-color: #3b3e3f;
  --focus-opacity: 0.5;
}

.toggle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 26px;
}

.toggle input {
  width: 0;
  height: 16px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.toggle_slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: var(--color-silver);
  transition: .3s;
  border-radius: 26px;
}

.toggle_slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  background-color: var(--color-white);
  transition: .3s;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.toggle_slider::after {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 26px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 2px solid var(--focus-color);
  margin: -3px;
  opacity: 0;
}

input:checked+.toggle_slider {
  background-color: var(--color-mint);
}

input:checked+.toggle_slider:before {
  transform: translateX(34px);
}

.toggle input:focus+.toggle_slider::after {
  opacity: var(--focus-opacity);
}
```

```html
<label class="toggle">
    <input type=checkbox aria-hidden="true" />
    <span class="toggle_slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Note: I don't want to resort to JavaScript if possible.

Comment: Guess your input field is in `:active` state when you keep the mouse button pressed down, so try and also add that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the CSS solution: You can target the pseudo selector `::after` on active state of the `.toggle_slider`

```
.toggle_slider:active::after{
  opacity: var(--focus-opacity);
}
```

```css
:root {
  --color-mint: #02b689;
  --color-white: #ffffff;
  --color-silver: #c2c2c2;
  --focus-color: #3b3e3f;
  --focus-opacity: 0.5;
}

.toggle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 26px;
}

.toggle input {
  width: 0;
  height: 16px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.toggle_slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: var(--color-silver);
  transition: .3s;
  border-radius: 26px;
}

.toggle_slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  background-color: var(--color-white);
  transition: .3s;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.toggle_slider::after {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 26px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 2px solid var(--focus-color);
  margin: -3px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.toggle_slider:active::after{
  opacity: var(--focus-opacity);
}

input:checked+.toggle_slider {
  background-color: var(--color-mint);
}

input:checked+.toggle_slider:before {
  transform: translateX(34px);
}

.toggle input:focus+.toggle_slider::after {
  opacity: var(--focus-opacity);
}
```

```html
<label class="toggle">
  <input type=checkbox aria-hidden="true"/>
  <span class="toggle_slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're experiencing is due to the default behavior of some browsers to remove the outline when an element is clicked or receives focus. This behavior is often associated with the CSS **:focus** pseudo-class.

To prevent the outline from disappearing when you click and hold the element, you can modify the **:focus** style to explicitly define the outline for the focused state.

```
.toggle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 26px;
}

.toggle input {
  width: 0;
  height: 16px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.toggle_slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: var(--color-silver);
  transition: .3s;
  border-radius: 26px;
}

/* Add the following style to explicitly define the outline for the :focus state */
.toggle input:focus + .toggle_slider {
  outline: 2px solid var(--focus-color);
  outline-offset: -1px;
}
```

With this modification, when the checkbox inside the **.toggle** element receives focus (e.g., when it is clicked), the **.toggle_slider** will have a 2px solid outline with the **--focus-color** specified in your **:root** block. The **outline-offset** is used to make the outline surround the element without affecting its size.

Now, when you click and hold the element, the outline will remain visible.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT